# jquery UI AutoComplete - embedding the list in another container

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

My app has a pretty unique style for all the popups that occur, and I can't make the generated jQuery UI Autocomplete html work to fit into that style. What I'd like to do is place the autocomplete into a pre-made container that's configured to drop in.

However, when I use the appendTo option, the list doesn't appear, and it seems to be because the style is positioning it somewhere outside the visible area of the popup.

```
$('#name').autocomplete({
  minLength: 0,
  source:"this,that,these,those".split(','),
  appendTo: '#popover-hook'
});
```

Everything works fine when appendTo isn't set.

So: is there a way to put the contents of the autocomplete into another div that's placed correctly already?

Comment: What does the markup for the existing `div` look like? How is it styled?

Comment: can you setup a http://jsfiddle.net with the current code?

Answer (score 4):

The autocomplete widget creates a UL element containing the suggestions.  The `appendTo` option specifies where that UL element gets inserted into the DOM.  By default, the UL element is appended to the BODY.  Styles are then used to position the UL in the correct location.

The autocomplete dropdown adds the `ui-autocomplete` and `ui-menu-item classes`.  You should be able to apply your style to those classes.  If not, can you give us an essence of the unique styles that?

For positioning, you can override the styling of the UL after the open event fires.  Here's an example of absolute positioning:

```
$('#name').autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source:"this,that,these,those".split(','),
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $(".ui-autocomplete").css("position", "absolute");
        $(".ui-autocomplete").css("top", "100px");
        $(".ui-autocomplete").css("left", "100px");
    }
});
```

Here is an example of positioning inside a container element:

```
$('#name').autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source:"this,that,these,those".split(','),
    appendTo: "#container",
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $(".ui-autocomplete").css("position", "relative");
        $(".ui-autocomplete").css("top", "0px");
        $(".ui-autocomplete").css("left", "0px");
    }
});
```

Comment: The plugin also puts a style into the ul that positions it absolutely, so even when I put it in my container it's hidden because it's positioned way off in the ether.

Comment: I thought you were concerned with the styling of the autocomplete drop down, not the position. If applying styling on the open event doesn't help you, please give more information, code, or diagrams of what look you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I was pretty explicit, saying I wanted to put the Autocomplete UL into a premade container configured to drop it in, and that the style is positioning it off the visible area of the container. Thanks, though.

Comment: So the lower example appends the UL to a container, and removes the absolute positioning.  Does that help fit your app's style?

Comment: I'll give that a run this weekend. If it works, it'll sure beat my previous plan to write something custom from scratch. :-) Thanks!